# How does docker store uploaded file? in a ram or hard disk?

Tags: docker

I try to make a simple file upload server. I wonder if it stores the uploaded file in a ram or hard disk since the container itself run as a virtual-machine in ram so it should not be able to have access to the disk right? unless I specify the bind-mounted volume option. So if the user upload a lot of files to the server at some points it's going to crash since it doesn't have ram space to store the files.

Answer (score 1):

This heavily depends on the implementation of the program inside the container.  If the program stores documents in memory, they'll be in memory in a container too; if it does a streaming upload to external storage, it will work that way in a container; if it stores the documents on disk, they'll be stored on disk in a container.

It is true that, without any mounted storage, the container filesystem is temporary, and anything you write there will be lost when the container exits.  It is stored on disk, however, unless you specifically set up a RAM disk mount.  The program should use more or less the same amount of memory in a container or not.